# One of Angular modules is missing

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, npm, http-status-code-404

I have `Angular4` integrated with `Visual Studio 2017` using [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2017/04/01/Set-Up-ASPNET-MVC.aspx?Page=1) article.
I also use `Nodejs 8.6.0` and `npm 5.4.2` (the latest versions at this time).
`vs2017` generated a folder named `node_modules` and all the sub folders/files without caching any error.
But `node_modules/systemjs` folder does not exist in it. It's been called in `<header>` tag like this: `<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>`. which result to **404 Not Found** page.
I also create an angular from the ground up without `VS2017` and it works like a charm! It doesn't have `node_modules/systemjs` folder either, but it works!!!
What is happening? And how should i bring this folder back? Does it related to the `Angular2` and is not supported in `Angular4`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries for loading modules for Angular: systemJS and Webpack. Depending on which technique you use to build your application, you will use one or the other.

For example, if you use the Angular CLI, it uses Webpack and you won't see systemJS in your project.

If you use the latest `dotnet new angular` for VS 2017, it uses Webpack as well.

If you build your application following the angular.io documentation, it uses systemJS.

Comment: Actually, i checked this out and ... neither "Webpack" nor "systemJS" exists in `package.json\dependencies` config file. How could i utilize `Webpack` on this matter?